# Why scaled animation rotates only half a way?

Tags: animation, armature, bones

These are simple cylinders with one bone. I've created a simple animation in smaller cylinder. I've noticed that when I scale the cylinder up, it rotates only half a way in its animation. 
I've made this comparison:

[image: half rotation]

Why the bigger mesh doesn't rotate at full angle, like the smaller one does? I feel that this is something really basic, but I don't get it. Please help.

Edit: Additional gif:

[image]

Comment: Do you have one bone influencing the other? If so is it by slider factor, driver, parent? Is the scale and rotation applied? Please add more info.

Comment: I can think of several possible reasons you might be seeing this behavior, but based upon the information you provided, cannot tell which one is correct for your situation. I suggest that you upload a copy of your ~.blend file to [Blend exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), or a similar site, to give those who might with to help you more information that they need.

Comment: Thanks, It turns out that it's a matter of Applying Scale after scaling in Blender... But if I export a skeletal mesh to Unreal Engine 4 and scale it there, it acts the same way - and there's no option to 'Apply Scale' in UE4. But I guess that it's a problem with UE4 then? 

Here is what happens after scaling inside an engine: (On the right - how it should look. On the left - animation with only-half-a-way rotation of bigger one) http://giphy.com/gifs/l0COIGtOS5LBvwyVq

Comment: (Can't edit previous comment anymore) Here's another example - this time I've created an animation inside UE4, to make sure that's not an animation's fault: http://giphy.com/gifs/xT0BKeKJdwBytjOBH2   - I just want to make an animation with 30 degrees rotation, but if I scale the mesh x2 in Z, it rotates only 15 degrees, etc. I'm curious if is there any logical explanation of this behavior, so I could investigate further from that.